# How to make the kernel for my bootloader?

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, bootloader, osdev

I'm trying to make my own custom OS and I need some help with my code.
This is my **bootloader.asm**:

```
[ORG 0x7c00]

start:
    cli
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl
    mov bp, 0x8000
    mov sp, bp
    mov bx, 0x9000
    mov dh, 5
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    call load_kernel
    call enable_A20
    call graphics_mode
    lgdt [gdtr]
    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm

[bits 32]
init_pm:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    jmp 0x9000

[BITS 16]
graphics_mode:
    mov ax, 0013h
    int 10h
    ret

load_kernel:
                        ; load DH sectors to ES:BX from drive DL
    push dx             ; Store DX on stack so later we can recall
                        ; how many sectors were request to be read ,
                        ; even if it is altered in the meantime
    mov ah , 0x02       ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al , dh         ; Read DH sectors
    mov ch , 0x00       ; Select cylinder 0
    mov dh , 0x00       ; Select head 0
    mov cl , 0x02       ; Start reading from second sector ( i.e.
                        ; after the boot sector )
    int 0x13            ; BIOS interrupt
    jc disk_error       ; Jump if error ( i.e. carry flag set )
    pop dx              ; Restore DX from the stack
    cmp dh , al         ; if AL ( sectors read ) != DH ( sectors expected )
    jne disk_error      ; display error message
    ret
disk_error :
    mov bx , ERROR_MSG
    call print_string
    hlt

[bits 32]
    ; prints a null - terminated string pointed to by EDX
print_string :
    pusha
    mov edx , VIDEO_MEMORY ; Set edx to the start of vid mem.
print_string_loop :
    mov al , [ ebx ] ; Store the char at EBX in AL
    mov ah , WHITE_ON_BLACK ; Store the attributes in AH
    cmp al , 0 ; if (al == 0) , at end of string , so
    je print_string_done ; jump to done
    mov [edx] , ax ; Store char and attributes at current
        ; character cell.
    add ebx , 1 ; Increment EBX to the next char in string.
    add edx , 2 ; Move to next character cell in vid mem.
    jmp print_string_loop ; loop around to print the next char.
print_string_done :
    popa
    ret ; Return from the function

[bits 16]
; Variables 
ERROR_MSG db "Error!" , 0
BOOT_DRIVE: db 0
VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x0f

%include "a20.inc"
%include "gdt.inc"

times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55
db 0xAA
```

I compile it with this:

```
nasm -f bin -o boot.bin bootloader.asm
```

This is **kernel.c**:

```
call_main(){main();}
void main(){}
```

I compile it with this:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -o kernel.bin kernel.c
```

and then:

```
cat boot.bin kernel.bin > os.bin
```

I want to know what I am doing wrong because when I test with *QEMU* it doesn't work. Can someone give some tips to improve `kernel.c` so I don't have to use the call_main() function?

When testing I use:

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel os.bin
```

---

### My Other Files

**a20.inc**:

```
   enable_A20:
call check_a20
cmp ax, 1
je enabled
call a20_bios
call check_a20
cmp ax, 1
je enabled
call a20_keyboard
call check_a20
cmp ax, 1
je enabled
call a20_fast
call check_a20
cmp ax, 1
je enabled
mov bx, [ERROR]
call print_string
   enabled:
ret


  check_a20:
pushf
push ds
push es
push di
push si

cli

xor ax, ax ; ax = 0
mov es, ax

not ax ; ax = 0xFFFF
mov ds, ax

mov di, 0x0500
mov si, 0x0510

mov al, byte [es:di]
push ax

mov al, byte [ds:si]
push ax

mov byte [es:di], 0x00
mov byte [ds:si], 0xFF

cmp byte [es:di], 0xFF

pop ax
mov byte [ds:si], al

pop ax
mov byte [es:di], al

mov ax, 0
je check_a20__exit

mov ax, 1

 check_a20__exit:
pop si
pop di
pop es
pop ds
popf

ret

    a20_bios:
mov ax, 0x2401
int 0x15
ret

    a20_fast:
in al, 0x92
or al, 2
out 0x92, al
ret

    [bits 32]
    [section .text]

    a20_keyboard:
    cli

    call    a20wait
    mov     al,0xAD
    out     0x64,al

    call    a20wait
    mov     al,0xD0
    out     0x64,al

    call    a20wait2
    in      al,0x60
    push    eax

    call    a20wait
    mov     al,0xD1
    out     0x64,al

    call    a20wait
    pop     eax
    or      al,2
    out     0x60,al

    call    a20wait
    mov     al,0xAE
    out     0x64,al

    call    a20wait
    sti
    ret

    a20wait:
    in      al,0x64
    test    al,2
    jnz     a20wait
    ret


    a20wait2:
    in      al,0x64
    test    al,1
    jz      a20wait2
    ret
```

**gdt.inc**:

```
 gdt_start:
dd 0                ; null descriptor--just fill 8 bytes    dd 0 

 gdt_code:
dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low
dw 0                ; base low
db 0                ; base middle
db 10011010b            ; access
db 11001111b            ; granularity
db 0                ; base high

 gdt_data:
dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low (Same as code)
dw 0                ; base low
db 0                ; base middle
db 10010010b            ; access
db 11001111b            ; granularity
db 0                ; base high
  end_of_gdt:

  gdtr: 
dw end_of_gdt - gdt_start - 1   ; limit (Size of GDT)
dd gdt_start            ; base of GDT

   CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
   DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

Comment: You should provide a complete example. For example you don't have the file `a20.inc` and `gdt.inc` as part of your question.

Comment: You don't set the SS (Stack segment).in your 16 bit code (after cli)

Comment: You might want to see this answer I gave regarding [bootloaders](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942) . In particular item 1. You should be setting _DS_ to 0 (something like `xor ax, ax` `mov ds, ax`). You need to at least be sure that the _DS_ is set to 0 since you've set ORG to 0x7c00. The BIOS won't guarantee that SS/DS/ES are set when you get loaded. `DL` will have the drive letter booted and physical address 0x00007c00 will be where code execution will start. **Don't assume that anything else is valid or what you expect**

Comment: Can you provide a _bootloader.asm_, _gdt.inc_ and _a20.inc_ that actually compile?  For instance  `ox90000` is an error and should be ` `0x90000` (it shouldn't even compile). The %include directives should have quotes around them etc. The point would be the code you need to provide us should at least be usable by nasm. There are missing functions in a20.inc too.

Comment: `gcc -ffreestanding -o kernel.bin kernel.c` is wrong. This doesn't create a flat binary. It output an elf object. There are so many problems with your code, I think you need to find a good tutorial about creating bootloaders and kernels.

Comment: Sorry abt the errors in the code. The code I posted is actually slightly outdated so I had fixed those errors (i.e. `0x90000`) before compiling. Do you think my bootloader is actually loading and jumping (successfully) to `0x9000` ? btw I sort of guessed that my kernel.c was not getting compiled correctly. Any tips on compiling that?

Comment: Please make a minimal example that reproduces the error. I'm keeping a bunch of minimal examples at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/ See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508919/how-to-produce-a-minimal-bios-hello-world-boot-sector-with-gcc-that-works-from-a

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are a number of issues, but in general your assembly code does work. I have written a StackOverflow answer that has tips for [general bootloader development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code/32705076#32705076).

## Don't Assume the Segment Registers are Set Properly

The original code in your question didn't set the *SS* stack segment register. Tip #1 I give is:

> When the BIOS jumps to your code you can't rely on CS,DS,ES,SS,SP
>   registers having valid or expected values. They should be set up
>   appropriately when your bootloader starts.

If you need *ES* it should be set as well. Although in your code it doesn't appear to be the case (except in the print_string function which I'll discuss later).

## Properly Define the GDT

The single largest bug that would have prevented you from getting far into protected mode was that you set up the global descriptor table (GDT) in *gdt.inc* starting with:

```
gdt_start:
    dd 0                ; null descriptor--just fill 8 bytes    dd 0
```

Each global descriptor needs to be 8 bytes but `dd 0` defines just 4 bytes (double word). It should be:

```
gdt_start:
    dd 0                ; null descriptor--just fill 8 bytes    
    dd 0
```

It actually appears that the second `dd 0` was accidentally added to the end of the comment on the previous line.

## When in 16-bit Real Mode Don't Use 32-bit Code

You have written some `print_string` code but it is 32-bit code:

```
[bits 32]
    ; prints a null - terminated string pointed to by EBX
print_string :
    pusha
    mov edx , VIDEO_MEMORY ; Set edx to the start of vid mem.
print_string_loop :
    mov al , [ ebx ] ; Store the char at EBX in AL
    mov ah , WHITE_ON_BLACK ; Store the attributes in AH
    cmp al , 0 ; if (al == 0) , at end of string , so
    je print_string_done ; jump to done
    mov [edx] , ax ; Store char and attributes at current
        ; character cell.
    add ebx , 1 ; Increment EBX to the next char in string.
    add edx , 2 ; Move to next character cell in vid mem.
    jmp print_string_loop ; loop around to print the next char.
print_string_done :
    popa
    ret ; Return from the function
```

You call *print_string* as an error handler in 16-bit code so what you are doing here will likely force a reboot of the computer. You can't use the 32-bit registers and addressing. The code can be made 16-bit with some adjustments:

```
    ; prints a null - terminated string pointed to by EBX
print_string :
    pusha
    push es                   ;Save ES on stack and restore when we finish

    push VIDEO_MEMORY_SEG     ;Video mem segment 0xb800
    pop es
    xor di, di                ;Video mem offset (start at 0)
print_string_loop :
    mov al , [ bx ] ; Store the char at BX in AL
    mov ah , WHITE_ON_BLACK ; Store the attributes in AH
    cmp al , 0 ; if (al == 0) , at end of string , so
    je print_string_done ; jump to done
    mov word [es:di], ax ; Store char and attributes at current
        ; character cell.
    add bx , 1 ; Increment BX to the next char in string.
    add di , 2 ; Move to next character cell in vid mem.
    jmp print_string_loop ; loop around to print the next char.

print_string_done :
    pop es                    ;Restore ES that was saved on entry
    popa
    ret ; Return from the function
```

The primary difference (in 16-bit code) is that we no longer use *EAX* and *EDX* 32-bit registers. In order to access the video ram @ *0xb8000* we need to use a  segment:offset pair that represents the same thing. *0xb8000* can be represented as segment:offset *0xb800:0x0* (Computed as (0xb800<<4)+0x0) = *0xb8000* physical address. We can use this knowledge to store *b800* in the *ES* register and use *DI* register as the offset to update video memory. We now use:

```
mov word [es:di], ax
```

To move a word into video ram.

## Assembling and Linking the Kernel and Bootloader

One of the issues you have in building your Kernel is that you don't properly generate a flat binary image that can be loaded into memory directly. Rather than using `gcc -ffreestanding -o kernel.bin kernel.c` I recommend doing it this way:

```
gcc -g -m32 -c -ffreestanding -o kernel.o kernel.c -lgcc
ld -melf_i386 -Tlinker.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o kernel.elf kernel.o
objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin
```

This assembles *kernel.c* to *kernel.o* with debugging info (`-g`). The linker then takes *kernel.o* (32-bit *ELF* binary) and produces an *ELF* executable called *kernel.elf* (this file will be handy if you want to debug your kernel). We then use *objcopy* to take the ELF32 executable file *kernel.elf* and convert it into a flat binary image *kernel.bin* that can be loaded by the BIOS. A key thing to note is that with `-Tlinker.ld` option we are asking the *LD*(linker) to read options from the file *linker.ld* . This is a simple `linker.ld` you can use to get started:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(main)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x9000;
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss  : { *(.bss) *(COMMON) }
}
```

The thing to note here is that `. = 0x9000` is telling the linker that it should produce an executable that will be loaded at memory address *0x9000* . `0x9000` is where you seem to have placed your kernel in your question. The rest of the lines make available the *C* sections that will need to be included into your kernel to work properly.

I recommend doing something similar when using *NASM* so rather than doing `nasm -f bin -o boot.bin bootloader.asm` do it this way:

```
nasm -g -f elf32 -F dwarf -o boot.o bootloader.asm
ld -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x7c00 -nostdlib --nmagic -o boot.elf boot.o
objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin
```

This is similar to compiling the *C* kernel. We don't use a linker script here, but we do tell the linker to produce our code assuming the code (bootloader) will be loaded at *0x7c00* .

For this to work you will need to **remove** this line from *bootloader.asm* :

```
[ORG 0x7c00]
```

## Cleanup The Kernel (kernel.c)

Modify your *kernel.c* file to be:

```
/* This code will be placed at the beginning of the object by the linker script */    
__asm__ (".pushsection .text.start\r\n" \
         "jmp main\r\n" \
         ".popsection\r\n"
         );

/* Place main as the first function defined in kernel.c so
 * that it will be at the entry point where our bootloader
 * will call. In our case it will be at 0x9000 */

int main(){
    /* Do Stuff Here*/

    return 0; /* return back to bootloader */
}
```

In *bootloader.asm* we should be calling the `main` function (that will be placed at 0x9000) rather than jumping to it. Instead of:

```
jmp 0x9000
```

Change it to:

```
    call 0x9000
    cli
loopend:                ;Infinite loop when finished
    hlt
    jmp loopend
```

The code after the call will be executed when *C* function main returns. It is a simple loop that will effectively halt the processor and remain that way indefinitely since we have no where to go back to.

## Code After Making All Recommended Changes

**bootloader.asm**:

```
[bits 16]

global _start
_start:
    cli
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x8000      ; Stack pointer at SS:SP = 0x0000:0x8000
    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl; Boot drive passed to us by the BIOS
    mov dh, 17          ; Number of sectors (kernel.bin) to read from disk
                        ; 17*512 allows for a kernel.bin up to 8704 bytes
    mov bx, 0x9000      ; Load Kernel to ES:BX = 0x0000:0x9000

    call load_kernel
    call enable_A20

;   call graphics_mode  ; Uncomment if you want to switch to graphics mode 0x13
    lgdt [gdtr]
    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm

graphics_mode:
    mov ax, 0013h
    int 10h
    ret

load_kernel:
                        ; load DH sectors to ES:BX from drive DL
    push dx             ; Store DX on stack so later we can recall
                        ; how many sectors were request to be read ,
                        ; even if it is altered in the meantime
    mov ah , 0x02       ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al , dh         ; Read DH sectors
    mov ch , 0x00       ; Select cylinder 0
    mov dh , 0x00       ; Select head 0
    mov cl , 0x02       ; Start reading from second sector ( i.e.
                        ; after the boot sector )
    int 0x13            ; BIOS interrupt
    jc disk_error       ; Jump if error ( i.e. carry flag set )
    pop dx              ; Restore DX from the stack
    cmp dh , al         ; if AL ( sectors read ) != DH ( sectors expected )
    jne disk_error      ; display error message
    ret
disk_error :
    mov bx , ERROR_MSG
    call print_string
    hlt

; prints a null - terminated string pointed to by EDX
print_string :
    pusha
    push es                   ;Save ES on stack and restore when we finish

    push VIDEO_MEMORY_SEG     ;Video mem segment 0xb800
    pop es
    xor di, di                ;Video mem offset (start at 0)
print_string_loop :
    mov al , [ bx ] ; Store the char at BX in AL
    mov ah , WHITE_ON_BLACK ; Store the attributes in AH
    cmp al , 0 ; if (al == 0) , at end of string , so
    je print_string_done ; jump to done
    mov word [es:di], ax ; Store char and attributes at current
        ; character cell.
    add bx , 1 ; Increment BX to the next char in string.
    add di , 2 ; Move to next character cell in vid mem.
    jmp print_string_loop ; loop around to print the next char.

print_string_done :
    pop es                    ;Restore ES that was saved on entry
    popa
    ret ; Return from the function

%include "a20.inc"
%include "gdt.inc"

[bits 32]
init_pm:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    call 0x9000
    cli
loopend:                                ;Infinite loop when finished
    hlt
    jmp loopend

[bits 16]
; Variables
ERROR            db "A20 Error!" , 0
ERROR_MSG        db "Error!" , 0
BOOT_DRIVE:      db 0

VIDEO_MEMORY_SEG equ 0xb800
WHITE_ON_BLACK   equ 0x0f

times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55
db 0xAA
```

**gdt.inc**:

```
gdt_start:
    dd 0                ; null descriptor--just fill 8 bytes
    dd 0

gdt_code:
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10011010b        ; access
    db 11001111b        ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high

gdt_data:
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low (Same as code)
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10010010b        ; access
    db 11001111b        ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high
end_of_gdt:

gdtr:
    dw end_of_gdt - gdt_start - 1   ; limit (Size of GDT)
    dd gdt_start        ; base of GDT

    CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
    DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

**a20.inc**:

```
enable_A20:
    call check_a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je enabled
    call a20_bios
    call check_a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je enabled
    call a20_keyboard
    call check_a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je enabled
    call a20_fast
    call check_a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je enabled
    mov bx, [ERROR]
    call print_string
enabled:
    ret

check_a20:
    pushf
    push ds
    push es
    push di
    push si

    cli
    xor ax, ax ; ax = 0
    mov es, ax
    not ax ; ax = 0xFFFF
    mov ds, ax
    mov di, 0x0500
    mov si, 0x0510
    mov al, byte [es:di]
    push ax
    mov al, byte [ds:si]
    push ax
    mov byte [es:di], 0x00
    mov byte [ds:si], 0xFF
    cmp byte [es:di], 0xFF
    pop ax
    mov byte [ds:si], al
    pop ax
    mov byte [es:di], al
    mov ax, 0
    je check_a20__exit
    mov ax, 1

check_a20__exit:
    pop si
    pop di
    pop es
    pop ds
    popf
    ret

a20_bios:
    mov ax, 0x2401
    int 0x15
    ret

a20_fast:
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    ret

    [bits 32]
    [section .text]

a20_keyboard:
    cli

    call    a20wait
    mov     al,0xAD
    out     0x64,al
    call    a20wait
    mov     al,0xD0
    out     0x64,al
    call    a20wait2
    in      al,0x60
    push    eax
    call    a20wait
    mov     al,0xD1
    out     0x64,al
    call    a20wait
    pop     eax
    or      al,2
    out     0x60,al
    call    a20wait
    mov     al,0xAE
    out     0x64,al
    call    a20wait
    sti
    ret

a20wait:
    in      al,0x64
    test    al,2
    jnz     a20wait
    ret

a20wait2:
    in      al,0x64
    test    al,1
    jz      a20wait2
    ret
```

**kernel.c**:

```
/* This code will be placed at the beginning of the object by the linker script */    
__asm__ (".pushsection .text.start\r\n" \
         "jmp main\r\n" \
         ".popsection\r\n"
         );

/* Place main as the first function defined in kernel.c so
 * that it will be at the entry point where our bootloader
 * will call. In our case it will be at 0x9000 */

int main(){
    /* Do Stuff Here*/

    return 0; /* return back to bootloader */
}
```

**linker.ld**

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(main)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x9000;
    .text : { *(.text.start) *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss  : { *(.bss) *(COMMON) }
}
```

## Create Disk Image Using DD / Debugging with QEMU

If you use the files above, and produce the required bootloader and kernel files using these commands (as mentioned previously)

```
nasm -g -f elf32 -F dwarf -o boot.o bootloader.asm
ld -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x7c00 -nostdlib --nmagic -o boot.elf boot.o
objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin

gcc -g -m32 -c -ffreestanding -o kernel.o kernel.c -lgcc
ld -melf_i386 -Tlinker.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o kernel.elf kernel.o
objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin
```

You can produce a disk image (in this case we'll make it the size of a floppy) with these commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=disk.img bs=512 conv=notrunc
dd if=kernel.bin of=disk.img bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc
```

This creates a zero filled disk image of size 512*2880 bytes (The size of a 1.44 megabyte floppy). `dd if=boot.bin of=disk.img bs=512 conv=notrunc` writes *boot.bin* to the first sector of the file without truncating the disk image. `dd if=kernel.bin of=disk.img bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc` places *kernel.bin* into the disk image starting at the second sector. The `seek=1` skips over the first block (bs=512) before writing.

If you wish to run your kernel you can launch it as floppy drive A: (`-fda`) in *QEMU* like this:

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda disk.img
```

You can also debug your 32-bit kernel using *QEMU* and the GNU Debugger (*GDB*) with the debug information we generated when compiling/assembling the code with the instructions above.

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda disk.img -S -s &
gdb kernel.elf  \
        -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' \
        -ex 'layout src' \
        -ex 'layout reg' \
        -ex 'break main' \
        -ex 'continue'
```

This example launches *QEMU* with the remote debugger and emulating a floppy disk using the file `disk.img`(that we created with *DD*). *GDB* launches using kernel.elf (a file we generated with debug info), then connects to *QEMU*, and sets a breakpoint at *function* main() in the *C* code. When the debugger finally is ready you'll be prompted to press `<return>` to continue. With any luck you should be viewing function *main* in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I'll check out the code and hope it works.  :)

Comment: @Michael Petch How about for a self-relocating boot/kernel dealing with the `-Ttext` argument in the linker?

Answer (score -1):

i think i know why it doesnt work, the bootloader must understand the ISO 9660 Structure when you put it into an iso file, because as one emerged file and not understanding the ISO file system, it doesnt know where the kernel is, i would prefer you test the raw files together in qemu.

Comment: This question doesn't mention CDs or ISO 9660 filesystems, does it? I think QEMU's default for a `.bin` is to treat it like a floppy or HD, like how a computer would treat a bootable USB stick or hard drive.   The man page (https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/qemu-system-x86/qemu-system-i386.1.en.html) says the OP's option `-kernel bzImage` wants a Linux kernel or a multiboot (ELF) kernel, so it shouldn't have a bootloader at all for that option.