# second stage bootloader loaded but not executing

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I am new to osdev and am trying to make a bootloader from scratch. I am currently trying to execute the second stage.
This is my main bootloader code

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

xor ax, ax
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7c00
mov bp, sp

cld

mov bx, boot_msg
call print

mov dx, [0x9000]
call print_hex

mov bx, 0x9000
mov dh, 2
mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]

call load_disk

mov dx, [0x9000]
call print_hex

jmp 0x9000

jmp $

boot_msg db "Booting cornoS", 0
%include "print.asm"
%include "print_hex.asm"
%include "load_disk.asm"
BOOT_DRIVE db 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Here is my code for the second stage of my bootloader:

```
dw 0xface
stage2:
  mov ax, cs
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  sti
  mov bx, stage2_called
  call print

  call enable_a20

  jmp $
%include "a20.asm"
;%include "print.asm"
stage2_called db "Stage two successfully called!", 0
```

And finally here is my code that reads the disk:

```
load_disk:
  pusha
  push dx

  mov ah, 0x02
  mov al, dh
  mov ch, 0x00
  mov cl, 0x02
  mov dh, 0x00

  int 0x13
  jc disk_error

  pop dx
  cmp al, dh
  jne sectors_error
  mov bx, read_disk_success
  call print
  popa
  ret

disk_error:
  mov bx, read_disk_failed
  call print
  mov dh, ah
  call print_hex
  jmp $

sectors_error:
  mov bx, incorrect_sectors
  call print
  jmp $
read_disk_success db "Successfully read disk!", 0
read_disk_failed db "Failed to read disk", 0
incorrect_sectors db "Incorrect number of sectors read", 0
```

And finally I compile and run with:

```
nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm

nasm -f elf32 -o stage2.o stage2.asm
ld -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x9000 -nostdlib --nmagic -o stage2.elf stage2.o
objcopy -O binary stage2.elf stage2.bin

dd if=/dev/zero of=corn.img bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=corn.img bs=512 conv=notrunc
dd if=stage2.bin of=corn.img bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc

qemu-system-i386 -fda corn.img
```

The second print_hex outputs 0xface but when I jump to 0x9000 Nothing happens. I have tried jmp 0x0000:0x9000 and I get the same result. I really have no idea what is going on.

Note: print.asm is not included in stage2.asm because a20.asm has print already included

Comment: A few questions:

1. Why is `%include "print.asm"` commented out in stage2.asm? Why do you not get a linker error for `print`?

2. In stage1, it calls print with ds=es=0, while in stage2, it calls print with ds=es=cs. If cs=0, this is the same, of course, but if cs≠0, it is probably incorrect.

3. I suggest removing `sti`, at least until the print is working, since it clearly isn't necessary for print.

Comment: Stage2 is built as 32-bit code, but it is called while still running in 16-bit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't a minimal complete verifiable example. I am having to improvise and fill in some of the gaps and clean things up.

Noticeable problems:

- Primary issue is that your second stage isn't actually running in 32-bit protected mode. When you jump to it from the bootloader it is still 16-bit realmode. You will have to enable A20 line, set up a GDT and switch to protected mode. Your code is modelled around [existing projects and tutorials](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/18-interrupts/boot) that usually include a `gdt.asm`, `switch_pm.asm`, and `32print_pm.asm`. The code below uses these files to get into protected mode and print using a 32-bit `print_string_pm` function. Printing in protected mode can't use the BIOS. Your stage 2 will effectively need a 16-bit realmode part and a 32-bit protected mode part.
- Your realmode code has a combination of calling `print` and `print_string`. I have modified it all and kept it consistent as `print_string`.
- You need to set the BOOT_DRIVE after you set DS, not before it.
- You have the signature `0xface` at the beginning of stage 2. You will need to jump to 2 bytes beyond it to avoid executing the signature as code. You also rely on *CS* being set as you copy it to *DS* and *ES*. You will need to ensure you set *CS* first. You can rectify that FAR JMP using 0x0000:0x9002. That will set *CS* to 0x0000 and IP to 0x9002.

The revised code could look like:

**boot.asm**:

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

xor ax, ax
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7c00
mov bp, sp
mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl            ; Save the boot drive after setting DS, not before

cld

mov bx, boot_msg
call print_string

mov dx, [0x9000]
call print_hex

mov bx, 0x9000
mov dh, 2
mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]

call load_disk

mov dx, [0x9000]
call print_hex

jmp 0x0000:0x9002               ; FAR JMP to second stage that sets CS to 0x0000
                                ; We use 9002 since the first 2 bytes are the stage2 sig

boot_msg db "Booting cornoS", 0
%include "print.asm"
%include "print_hex.asm"
%include "load_disk.asm"

BOOT_DRIVE db 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

**stage2.asm**:

```
bits 16
dw 0xface
stage2:

  ; Still in 16-bit realmode at this point
  mov ax, cs
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  mov bx, stage2_called
  call print_string

  ; Enter protected mode
  ; Should check for A20 being enabled before enabling it
  ; For the original poster to clean up

  call enable_a20
  call switch_to_pm

%include "print.asm"
%include "a20.asm"
%include "switch_pm.asm"
%include "gdt.asm"

bits 32
BEGIN_PM:
  mov ebx, stage2_in_pm
  call print_string_pm
  jmp $

%include "32print_pm.asm"

stage2_called db "Stage two successfully called!", 0
stage2_in_pm db "In protected mode!", 0
```

**load_disk.asm**:

```
load_disk:
  pusha
  push dx

  mov ah, 0x02
  mov al, dh
  mov ch, 0x00
  mov cl, 0x02
  mov dh, 0x00

  int 0x13
  jc disk_error

  pop dx
  cmp al, dh
  jne sectors_error
  mov bx, read_disk_success
  call print_string
  popa
  ret

disk_error:
  mov bx, read_disk_failed
  call print_string
  mov dh, ah
  call print_hex
  jmp $

sectors_error:
  mov bx, incorrect_sectors
  call print_string
  jmp $
read_disk_success db "Successfully read disk!", 0
read_disk_failed db "Failed to read disk", 0
incorrect_sectors db "Incorrect number of sectors read", 0
```

**print.asm**:

```
print_string:
    pusha

; keep this in mind:
; while (string[i] != 0) { print string[i]; i++ }

; the comparison for string end (null byte)
start:
    mov al, [bx] ; 'bx' is the base address for the string
    cmp al, 0
    je done

    ; the part where we print with the BIOS help
    mov ah, 0x0e
    int 0x10 ; 'al' already contains the char

    ; increment pointer and do next loop
    add bx, 1
    jmp start

done:
    popa
    ret



print_nl:
    pusha

    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x0a ; newline char
    int 0x10
    mov al, 0x0d ; carriage return
    int 0x10

    popa
    ret
```

**print_hex.asm**:

```
print_hex:
    ; manipulate chars at HEX_OUT to reflect DX
    mov cx, dx
    and cx, 0xf000
    shr cx, 12
    call to_char
    mov [HEX_OUT + 2], cx

    mov cx, dx
    and cx, 0x0f00
    shr cx, 8
    call to_char
    mov [HEX_OUT + 3], cx

    mov cx, dx
    and cx, 0x00f0
    shr cx, 4
    call to_char
    mov [HEX_OUT + 4], cx

    mov cx, dx
    and cx, 0x000f
    call to_char
    mov [HEX_OUT + 5], cx

    mov bx, HEX_OUT
    call print_string
    mov byte [HEX_OUT + 2], '0'
    mov byte [HEX_OUT + 3], '0'
    mov byte [HEX_OUT + 4], '0'
    mov byte [HEX_OUT + 5], '0'
    ret

to_char:
    cmp cx, 0xa
    jl digits
    sub cx, 0xa
    add cx, 'a'
    ret
digits:
    add cx, '0'
    ret

HEX_OUT: db '0x0000', 0
```

**a20.asm**:

```
;;
;; NASM 32bit assembler
;;
;; From OSDev Wiki

enable_a20:
        cli

        call    a20wait
        mov     al,0xAD
        out     0x64,al

        call    a20wait
        mov     al,0xD0
        out     0x64,al

        call    a20wait2
        in      al,0x60
        push    eax

        call    a20wait
        mov     al,0xD1
        out     0x64,al

        call    a20wait
        pop     eax
        or      al,2
        out     0x60,al

        call    a20wait
        mov     al,0xAE
        out     0x64,al

        call    a20wait
        sti
        ret

a20wait:
        in      al,0x64
        test    al,2
        jnz     a20wait
        ret


a20wait2:
        in      al,0x64
        test    al,1
        jz      a20wait2
        ret
```

**gdt.asm**:

```
gdt_start: ; don't remove the labels, they're needed to compute sizes and jumps
    ; the GDT starts with a null 8-byte
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte

; GDT for code segment. base = 0x00000000, length = 0xfffff
; for flags, refer to os-dev.pdf document, page 36
gdt_code:
    dw 0xffff    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10011010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 24-31

; GDT for data segment. base and length identical to code segment
; some flags changed, again, refer to os-dev.pdf
gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_end:

; GDT descriptor
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size (16 bit), always one less of its true size
    dd gdt_start ; address (32 bit)

; define some constants for later use
CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

**switch_pm.asm**:

```
[bits 16]
switch_to_pm:
    cli ; 1. disable interrupts
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; 2. load the GDT descriptor
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1 ; 3. set 32-bit mode bit in cr0
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm ; 4. far jump by using a different segment

[bits 32]
init_pm: ; we are now using 32-bit instructions
    mov ax, DATA_SEG ; 5. update the segment registers
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000 ; 6. update the stack right at the top of the free space
    mov esp, ebp

    call BEGIN_PM ; 7. Call a well-known label with useful code
```

**32print_pm.asm**:

```
[bits 32] ; using 32-bit protected mode

; this is how constants are defined
VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000
WHITE_OB_BLACK equ 0x0f ; the color byte for each character

print_string_pm:
    pusha
    mov edx, VIDEO_MEMORY

print_string_pm_loop:
    mov al, [ebx] ; [ebx] is the address of our character
    mov ah, WHITE_OB_BLACK

    cmp al, 0 ; check if end of string
    je print_string_pm_done

    mov [edx], ax ; store character + attribute in video memory
    add ebx, 1 ; next char
    add edx, 2 ; next video memory position

    jmp print_string_pm_loop

print_string_pm_done:
    popa
    ret
```

You can use the same commands you used before to build the disk image:

```
nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm

nasm -f elf32 -o stage2.o stage2.asm
ld -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x9000 -nostdlib --nmagic -o stage2.elf stage2.o
objcopy -O binary stage2.elf stage2.bin

dd if=/dev/zero of=corn.img bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=corn.img bs=512 conv=notrunc
dd if=stage2.bin of=corn.img bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc

qemu-system-i386 -fda corn.img
```

The output should appear something like:

[image]

---

### More Advanced print_string_pm function

The generic `print_string_pm` in most of the tutorials starts printing in the upper left of the screen and is very basic. I wrote some example code for a more advanced `print_string_pm` function that:

- Continues printing in protected where the BIOS TTY functions left off
- Supports scrolling down
- Takes a color attribute to print with
- Takes a color attribute to fill the bottom line with when scrolling occurs
- Handles line wrapping
- Supports backspace, but not beyond beginning of screen
- Handles Carriage Return and Line Feed
- Ignores the TAB character
- Requires calling `call update_screen_state_from_bios` once after entering protected mode
- Updates the hardware cursor when finished

**32print_pm.asm**:

```
bits 32

VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR     EQU 0xb8000 ; Hard code beginning of text video memory

CR                  EQU 0x0d    ; Carriage return
LF                  EQU 0x0a    ; Line feed
BS                  EQU 0x08    ; Back space
TAB                 EQU 0x09    ; Tab

; Function: update_screen_info_from_bios
;           set the hardware cursor position based on the
;           current column (cur_col) and current row (cur_row) coordinates
;
; Inputs:   None
; Clobbers: EAX
; Returns:  None

update_screen_state_from_bios:
    xor eax, eax                ; Clear EAX for the instructions below
    mov al, [0x450]             ; Byte at address 0x450 = last BIOS column position
    mov [cur_col], eax          ; Copy to current column

    mov al, [0x451]             ; Byte at address 0x451 = last BIOS row position
    mov [cur_row], eax          ; Copy to current row

    mov al, [0x484]             ; Word at address 0x484 = # of rows-1 (screen height)
    mov [screen_height],eax     ; Copy to screen height

    mov ax, [0x44a]             ; Word at address 0x44a = # of columns (screen width)
    mov [screen_width], eax     ; Copy to screen width

    ret

; Function: set_cursor
;           set the hardware cursor position based on the
;           current column (cur_col) and current row (cur_row) coordinates
; See:      https://wiki.osdev.org/Text_Mode_Cursor#Moving_the_Cursor_2
;
; Inputs:   None
; Clobbers: EAX, ECX, EDX
; Returns:  None

set_cursor:
    mov ecx, [cur_row]          ; EAX = cur_row
    imul ecx, [screen_width]    ; ECX = cur_row * screen_width
    add ecx, [cur_col]          ; ECX = cur_row * screen_width + cur_col

    ; Send low byte of cursor position to video card
    mov edx, 0x3d4
    mov al, 0x0f
    out dx, al                  ; Output 0x0f to 0x3d4
    inc edx
    mov al, cl
    out dx, al                  ; Output lower byte of cursor pos to 0x3d5

    ; Send high byte of cursor position to video card
    dec edx
    mov al, 0x0e
    out dx, al                  ; Output 0x0e to 0x3d4
    inc edx
    mov al, ch
    out dx, al                  ; Output higher byte of cursor pos to 0x3d5

    ret

; Function: print_string_pm
;           Display a string to the console on display page 0 in protected mode.
;           Handles carriage return, line feed, and backspace. Tab characters
;           are not processed. Scrolling and wrapping are supported.
;           Backspacing beyond the first line does nothing.
;
; Inputs:   ESI = Offset of address to print
;           AH  = Attribute of string to print
;           AL  = Attribute to use when filling bottom line during down scrolling
; Clobbers: ECX, EDX
; Returns:  None

print_string_pm:
    push edi
    push esi
    push eax
    push ebx
    push ebp

    ; Assume base of text video memory is ALWAYS 0xb8000
    mov ebx, VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR    ; EBX = beginning of video memory
    mov cl, al                  ; CL = attribute to use for clearing while scrolling
    call .init                  ; Initialize register state for use while printing
    jmp .getch
.repeat:
    cmp al, CR                  ; Is the character a carriage return?
    jne .chk_lf                 ;     If not skip and check for line feed
    lea edi, [ebx + edx * 2]    ; Set current video memory pointer to beginning of line
    mov dword [cur_col], 0      ; Set current column to 0
    xor al, al                  ; AL = 0 = Don't print character
    jmp .chk_bounds             ; Check screen bounds
.chk_lf:
    ; Process line feed
    cmp al, LF                  ; Is the character a line feed?
    jne .chk_bs                 ;     If not check for backspace
    mov ebp, [screen_width]
    lea edi, [edi + ebp * 2]    ; Set current video memory ptr to same pos on next line
    inc dword [cur_row]         ; Set current row to next line
    xor al, al                  ; AL = 0 = Don't print character
    jmp .chk_bounds             ; Check screen bounds

.chk_bs:
    ; Process back space
    cmp al, BS                  ; Is the character a Back space?
    jne .chk_tab                ;     If not check for tab
    cmp edi, ebx
    je .getch                   ; If at beginning of display, ignore and get next char
    dec dword [cur_col]         ; Set current column to previous column
    jmp .chk_bounds             ; Check screen bounds

    ; Process tab - ignore character
.chk_tab:
    cmp al, TAB                 ; Is the character a Tab?
    je .getch                   ;     If it is, skip and get next character

    ; Check row and column boundaries and clip them if necessary
    ; If we exceed the number of rows on display,scroll down by a line
.chk_bounds:
    mov ebp, [screen_width]     ; EAX=screen width
    cmp [cur_col], ebp          ; Have we reached edge of display?
    jl  .chk_col_start          ;     If not - continue by checking for beginning of line
    mov dword [cur_col], 0      ; Reset current column to beginning of line
    inc dword [cur_row]         ; Advance to the next row
    jmp .chk_rows               ; Check number of rows in bounds
.chk_col_start:
    cmp dword [cur_col], 0      ; Check if beginning of line
    jge .chk_rows               ; If not negative (beginning of line) check row bounds
    mov dword [cur_col], 0      ; Set column to 0
.chk_rows:
    mov ebp, [screen_height]    ; EAX=screen width
    cmp [cur_row], ebp          ; Have we reached edge of display?
    jle  .test_char             ;     If not then continue by updating display
    dec dword [cur_row]         ; Back one row since we will be scrolling down a line
    call .scroll_down_one_line  ; Scroll display down by a line
    call .init                  ; Reinitialize register state after scroll

    ; Display character to video memory at current location if not a NUL character
.test_char:
    test al, al                 ; Is the character 0?
    jz .getch                   ;     If it is we are finished, get next character
    cmp al, BS                  ; Is the character a Back space?
    jne .not_bs                 ;     If not back space print char and advance cursor
    mov al, ' '
    sub edi, 2                  ; Go back one cell in video memory
    mov [es:edi], al            ; Print a space to clear previous character
    jmp .getch                  ; Don't advance cursor and get next character
.not_bs:
    stosw                       ; Update current character at current location
    inc dword [cur_col]         ; Advance the current column by 1 position

    ; Get next character from string parameter
.getch:
    lodsb                       ; Get character from string
    test al, al                 ; Have we reached end of string?
    jnz .repeat                 ;     if not process next character

.end:
    call set_cursor             ; Update hardware cursor position

    pop ebp
    pop ebx
    pop eax
    pop esi
    pop edi
    ret

; Function: print_string_pm.scroll_down_one_line
;           Internal function of print_string_pm to scroll the display down
;           by a single line. The top line is lost and the bottom line is
;           filled with spaces.
;
; Inputs:   EBX = Base address of video page
;           AH  = Attribute to use when clearing last line
; Clobbers: None
; Returns:  None, display updated

.scroll_down_one_line:
    pusha
    mov ebp, [screen_height]    ; EBP = (num_rows-1)
    mov eax, [screen_width]     ; EAX = screen_width
    lea esi, [ebx + eax * 2]    ; ESI = pointer to second line on screen
    mov edi, ebx                ; EDI = pointer to first line on screen
    mul ebp                     ; EAX = screen_width * (num_rows-1)
    mov ecx, eax                ; ECX = number of screen cells to copy
    rep movsw
    lea edi, [ebx + eax * 2]    ; Destination offset =
                                ; last row = screen_width * (num_rows-1)
    mov ecx, [screen_width]     ; Update a rows worth of word cells
    mov ah, cl
    mov al, ' '                 ; Use a space character with current background attribute
    rep stosw                   ; to clear the last line.
    popa
    ret


; Function: print_string_pm.init
;           Internal function of print_string_pm to compute the video memory
;           address of the current cursor location and the address to the
;           beginning of the current line
;
; Inputs:   EBX = Base address of video page
; Returns:  EDI = Current video memory offset of cursor
;           EDX = Video memory offset to beginning of line
; Clobbers: None

.init:
    push eax
    mov eax, [cur_row]          ; EAX = cur_row
    mul dword [screen_width]    ; EAX = cur_row * screen_width
    mov edx, eax                ; EDX = copy of offset to beginning of line
    add eax, [cur_col]          ; EAX = cur_row * screen_width + cur_col
    lea edi, [ebx + eax * 2]    ; EDI = memory location of current screen cell
    pop eax
    ret

align 4
cur_row:      dd 0x00
cur_col:      dd 0x00
screen_width: dd 0x00
screen_height:dd 0x00
```

**stage2.asm**:

```
ATTR_WHITE_ON_BLACK EQU 0x07    ; White on black attribute

bits 16
dw 0xface
stage2:

  ; Still in 16-bit realmode at this point
  mov ax, cs
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  mov bx, stage2_called
  call print_string

  ; Enter protected mode
  ; Should check for A20 being enabled before enabling it
  ; For the original poster to clean up

  call enable_a20
  call switch_to_pm

%include "print.asm"
%include "a20.asm"
%include "switch_pm.asm"
%include "gdt.asm"

bits 32
BEGIN_PM:
  ; Advanced print_string_pm needs to be initialized with the coordinate and screen
  ; info from the BIOS to continue here the BIOS left off.
  call update_screen_state_from_bios

  ; Advanced print_string_pm takes the address of the string in ESI and
  ; attribute information in AX (AL/AH).

  mov esi, stage2_in_pm
  mov ah, ATTR_WHITE_ON_BLACK   ; Attribute to print with
  mov al, ah                    ; Attribute to clear last line when scrolling

  call print_string_pm
  jmp $

%include "32print_pm.asm"

stage2_called db "Stage two successfully called!", 0
stage2_in_pm db "In protected mode!", 0
```

The output should appear something like:

[image]

Comment: the second stage was called but nothing was printed out in pmode. I made a separate folder and copied everything to test it, and in protected mode! was not printed

Comment: @Corn_11 : If you used the exact files from my post (using the first version of print_string_pm) did you look at the very first line in QEMU for the protected mode string? (It should have been printed in the upper left hand corner of the display)

Comment: @Corn_11 : I just copy and pasted everything in my answer into a new directory and built it up and it works just as expected. I have added screenshot of QEMU running it and have circled the text in red. I also copy and pasted the more advanced version of 32print_pm.asm (and stage2.asm) and it worked as expected. Screenshot provided in my answer now.

Comment: how would I go about loading my kernel? what address should it be at?

Comment: @Corn_11 Are you asking how to load your kernel from stage2? While it is in real mode you'd have to use something similar to disk load and place it into memory. You could start by writing it after stage2 in memory at a location like 0x0000:0xa000 which is 1024 from the start of stage2 (stage2 as loaded starting at 0x0000:0x9000).

Comment: @Corn_11:  As a beginner you could load it from realmode in stage1 (boot.asm) or stage2.asm (before switching to protected mode). To load it once in protected mode requires you interacting directly with the hardware since you don't have access to the BIOS interrupts once in protected mode and that is not easy for someone new to this.

Comment: I add the same disk load code after the first except with 0xa000 in bx. and added a jmp 0x0000:0xa000. I used the same kernel code as the answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603842/how-to-make-the-kernel-for-my-bootloader I am getting a triple fault on qemu.

Comment: @Corn_11 : without seeing all the code and how you are using it I can't say. Consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The second stage is loaded at 0x9000, and then it jumps to 0x9000, but the first thing at that address isn't an instruction; it is 0xface.* You need to jump to 0x9002, or else remove the `dw 0xface`.

---

* Of course, actually that is an instruction, or rather two instructions:
`0xce` = `INTO`
`0xfa` = `CLI`

The behavior of `INTO` is dependent on the value of the `O` flag, which is dependent on the last thing done in the previous `print_hex` call.

Comment: this does not work, I deleted 0xface and still got the same result. I also tried leaving it and jumping to 0x9002 and still got nothing.

Comment: I'm not surprised--this is tricky stuff, and there is likely to be more than one problem. This is the first one I noticed. I'll keep looking.