# My os is not printing out characters to the screen

Tags: c++, assembly, operating-system, kernel, osdev

My kernel is not printing characters onto the screen.

This is my boot.asm file:

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
    ; Set up the stack
    mov esp, 0x90000

    ; Load the kernel
    mov ah, 0x02 ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al, 1    ; Number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0    ; Cylinder number
    mov dh, 0    ; Head number
    mov dl, 0x80 ; Drive number (0x80 for the first hard drive)
    mov bx, 0x1000 ; Load to address 0x1000 (where we'll jump to)

    int 0x13     ; BIOS interrupt: read sectors into memory
    jc disk_error ; Jump if carry flag set (error)

    ; Jump to the kernel
    jmp 0x1000

disk_error:
    ; Handle disk error here (you can add more code)
    hlt

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55 ; Boot signature
```

Heres my kernel.cpp file:

```
extern "C" void kernelMain() {
    // Pointer to the video memory (text mode buffer)
    char* videoMemory = (char*)0xB8000;

    // Message to be displayed
    const char* message = "Hello, OS!";

    // Set the attribute byte (white on black)
    char attributeByte = 0x07;

    // Loop to print the message to the screen
    for (int i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        // Calculate the memory offset
        int offset = i * 2;

        // Set the character and attribute in video memory
        videoMemory[offset] = message[i];
        videoMemory[offset + 1] = attributeByte;
    }

    // Infinite loop to halt the CPU
    while (1) {
        asm("hlt");
    }
}
```

And finally my compile.bat file:

```
@echo off
REM Compile the kernel source code (kernel.cpp)
g++ -ffreestanding -c -o kernel.o kernel.cpp

REM Link the kernel object file and set the entry point at 0x1000
ld -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel.elf kernel.o

REM Convert the ELF kernel binary to a flat binary
objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin

REM Assemble the bootloader (boot.asm) to produce boot.bin
nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm

REM Concatenate the bootloader and kernel into os.img
powershell -Command "[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('os.img', [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('boot.bin') + [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('kernel.bin'))"

REM Run the OS using QEMU
qemu-system-i386 -fda os.img
```

When I compile & run my os it finds the os and just stops and doesn't print out anything onto the screen. I tried to change the compiler script a bit but it just didn't work.

Comment: When you single-step your bootloader using GDB (with QEMU as a GDB-remote), what do you see?  Also, Bochs has a built-in debugger that's aware of segmentation and what mode the CPU is in, so that would probably be better.  Your 16-bit bootlader never switches to 32 or 64-bit mode before jumping to code compiled with `g++` without a `-m16` option, so that's one problem for sure.  (Even then, 32-bit pointers won't work, since they're outside the 64K segment limits.)

Comment: You did not switch to protected mode at all, so stuff like `mov esp, 0x90000` or `char* videoMemory = (char*)0xB8000;` will not work.

Comment: You also don't set the DS or ES segment bases before calling `int 13h`, so you don't actually know what linear address your "kernel" got loaded at.  CS base can be different from DS or ES bases.  You also didn't set SS before setting SP, so you don't know what addresses your stack is overwriting.  Also, `mov esp, 0x90000` sets SP to `0000`, and the stack address size is still 16 in 16-bit real mode, so push/pop and interrupts are using `ss:0000`; after the first push, that'll be `ss:FFFC`.

Comment: TL:DR: This attempt left out a boatload of things.  [How to make the kernel for my bootloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33603842) explains most of them, and shows working code and build commands for all of them, including switching to 32-bit protected mode so you can call `g++ -m32` output.  Seems like a pretty close duplicate since that question was also trying to make a bootloader + 32-bit freestanding test program.